Sending user data from android app to the kamailio server while sending a call request
I’m trying to create a simple android application which extracts user’s location and also uses kamailio server (version 5.8) to make a call. Is there any way that when a user calls using my application the location data i.e latitude and longitude reaches to the kamailio server along with the call and kamailio logs it along with the call.
I’m new to kamailio so thanks in advance for any help…
Also I’ve already gotten handying with kamailio logging facility.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

add  sip headers to INVITE:
sip_h_X-xxx="youye user data"

Simplest method send some data via SIP protocol is use of SIP MESSAGE packet.
Which is supported by most libraries available.
After that you have parse all MESSAGE events in kamailio config and find it is your format, if it is - route it acordinly.
You also can add SIP headers to original INVITE method.
